# Trying to override a specific http header with proxy_pass

Tags: nginx

Using Nginx, I'm trying to override the content-type for wasm resources delivered by a backend server

as follows :

```
        location / {
            rewrite ^(/.*)$ $1 break;

            # Match requests ending with .wasm
            if ($uri ~* \.wasm$) {
                  rewrite ^ /bogus last;
            }
            add_header "X-Debug" $uri;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5173;
    }

    location = /bogus {
            access_log /var/log/nginx-bogus.log;
            internal;
            proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:5173;
            proxy_hide_header       Content-Type;
            add_header Content-Type application/wasm;
    }
```

my only issue is that this is not working as expected, I don't feel like my requests are redirected as expected,

what am I doing wrong here ?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Did you try just setting the header related directives directly in the if clause?

Comment: your `# Match requests ending with .wasm` never happens because of `break` in `rewrite` above.

Comment: And you don't need any rewrite at all. Just use `location /` and `location ~ \.wasm$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `rewrite`.
Just use two `location`s.

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5173;
    add_header "X-Debug" $uri;
}

location ~ \.wasm$ {
    access_log /var/log/nginx-bogus.log;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5173;
    proxy_hide_header Content-Type;
    add_header "X-Debug" $uri;
    add_header Content-Type application/wasm;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot ! this made my day !